# iMacros - change URL and save screen shot

Tags: url, loops, imacros

So, I'm trying to get iMacros to go to an URL and take a screen shot:

url~place/something/something/########.jpg

It works, of course, but now I want it to loop and go through tons of numbers.
I'm starting at 900000000 and want it to loop through 900100000 while saving a screen shot of the web page only if it loads successfully.

I have searched around for hours and found some scripts some people have used, but I haven't been able to get anything to work. I don't even know where to start really.

Thanks!

Comment: Which of the scripts have you tried? What exactly didn't work with them?

Comment: VERSION BUILD=7401110 RECORDER=CR SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO SET !ERRORIGNORE YES TAB T=1 SET !LOOP 900000000 URL GOTO=aa/aa/aa{{!LOOP}}.jpg SAVEAS TYPE=PNG FOLDER=* FILE=Time_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}}.png

Comment: I tried using this to get it to loop from 900000000 through 900100000. But it returns an error when I use the Play(Loop) button:

Comment: Error -1200: !LOOP must be less or equal to maximum loop counter.Try using "Play loop" instead of Play

Comment: VERSION BUILD=7401110 RECORDER=CR

SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
 
TAB T=1 
SET !LOOP 10000
URL GOTO=https://ftp2.weber.k12.ut.us/~photos/allstudents/9000{{!LOOP}}.jpg
SAVEAS TYPE=PNG FOLDER=* FILE=Time_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}}.png

Comment: It works now, but how do I make it so it doesn't save pictures if the webpage doesn't load to a legit page? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by ######## you mean a number that is changable then you can use this.

```
URL GOTO=url~place/something/something/{{!loop}}.jpg
```

This is an example for link. The key part is {{!loop}} . When you set number of loops and press play on iMacros the {{!loop}} will change from 1 to the number of loops you placed.

Comment: VERSION BUILD=7401110 RECORDER=CR

SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
 
TAB T=1 
SET !LOOP 900000000 
URL GOTO=https://aa/aa/aa/{{!LOOP}}.jpg
SAVEAS TYPE=PNG FOLDER=* FILE=Time_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}}.png

Comment: I'm trying to get it to loop through 900000000 - 900010000 and save any webpages that are legit.

Comment: VERSION BUILD=7401110 RECORDER=CR SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO SET !ERRORIGNORE YES TAB T=1 SET !LOOP 10000 URL GOTO=ftp2.weber.k12.ut.us/~photos/allstudents/9000{{!LOOP}}.jpg SAVEAS TYPE=PNG FOLDER=* FILE=Time_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}}.png

Comment: It works now, but how do I make it so it doesn't save pictures if the webpage doesn't load to a legit page? Thanks!